# Python Django- get or post?

Tags: jquery, python, django, post, get

I have a Django project, and on one of the webpages, I want to collect some information for a project.

One of the fields has a drop down list, from which the user can select the name of a member of the team involved in the project. This drop down list has a number of pre-defined choices, and also gives the option to select 'Other'.

If the user selects 'other', the 'drop down list' field changes to a 'text box', and the user can type in the name of the person they want to select. As they start typing, the database is queried based on the letters that they have typed so far, and a list of the available options (matching the letters typed) is displayed below the text box. For example, if the user had typed "D", the list of available options that would be displayed might include: 'Dan', 'Dave', 'Debbie', but if they had typed "Da", the list of available options that would be displayed would only include: 'Dan'& 'Dave'.

When the user first loads this page on a project, the 'name' field is empty. When I start typing in that field, and select an option from the list of available options that is displayed, the browser console shows me an error which says:

```
jquery-2.2.2.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/projects/5915/submit_3_5_ajax/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I thought that this might mean I'm using the wrong method, but I've tried using both `Get` & `Post`, and they both give the same error in the browser console...

The python console also shows this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
[10/Nov/2016 14:05:38] "POST /projects/5915/submit_3_5_ajax/ HTTP/1.1" 500 21537
```

As far as I can tell, the exception is occurring somewhere inside the form class in my `forms.py` file:

```
class InfoForm(ValidatedForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        try:
            who_will_organise = project.assigned.get(role=Role.O).employee.first_name + project.assigned.get(role=Role.O).employee.surname[0] # I just want to get the first character of the surname here...
        except ObjectDoesNotExist: who_will_organise = None

        ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        ...
        if data['who_will_organise']:
            ...
        else:
            # The print statements I'm seeing in the console would indicate that this is where the exception is being thrown...
            who_will_organise = Employee.objects.get(id=data['who_will_organise'])
            try:
                ...
            except ...
            ...
        ...
        return ...
```

The URL for the page is:

```
url(r'^(?P<project_id>\d+)/survey/$', views.survey, name='survey'),
```

and the `view` that it's calling is defined with:

```
def survey(request, project_id):
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    survey = Survey.objects.get_or_create(project=project)[0]

    context = {
        'project': project,
        'survey_form': SurveyInformationForm(instance=survey),
    }
    return render(request, 'projects/survey.html', context)
```

My browser console is displaying the following error messages:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/projects/5915/submit_3_5_ajax/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

autosave_form.js:122 FAIL: (){return f&&(c&&!b&&(h=f.length-1,g.push(c)),function d(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){n.isFunction(c)?a.unique&&j.has(c)||f.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==n.type(c)&&d(c)})}(arguments),c&&!b&&i…

FAIL: (){return f&&(c&&!b&&(h=f.length-1,g.push(c)),function d(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){n.isFunction(c)?a.unique&&j.has(c)||f.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==n.type(c)&&d(c)})}(arguments),c&&!b&&i…
```

In the Python console in my command line, where I'm running the Python server, I get the error message:

```
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'costing_addomit.group_id' in 'field list'")
[10/Nov/2016 15:01:24] "GET /projects/pipeline/ HTTP/1.1" 500 337434
```

Can anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Not with the detail you've shown; and it's not clear why you think this is related to get vs post. You'll need to show your urls.py, view, and the full error as shown in the browser dev tools network tab.

Comment: Apologies- I've added the URL and view to the question.

Comment: The URL you post to does not contain ".../survey/..." in it...

Comment: Yes, the URL I post to does contain `/survey/` - it's there in the `return render` line... The way I got to that view in Sublime was by right clicking on the URL and clicking 'Go to definition'... The URL displayed in my browser for the page on which I'm having the problem is: `http://localhost:8000/projects/5915/survey/`

Comment: No, we need to see the view and URL for the Ajax request to projects/5915/submit_3_5_ajax/. And, as I mentioned, the actual error from the browser dev tools.

Comment: I've added in the error messages that are being displayed in my browser console- is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't know where the view and URL for the Ajax request would be... I've only just taken on this project, and not used Python/ Django much before...

Comment: I've added the error that's being shown in the command line, where I'm running the Python server- is that helpful at all?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're casting a String as an Int somewhere.

A similar thing happened to me a while ago. A stack trace and/or printing stuff a your best friend here. 
My best guess is that the above code works and the problem is actually somewhere else.

Check where you're casting to an int, or expecting a null to not be null. The problem is probably there.

Comment: The python console is displaying a `ValueError`: `File "/.../site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 976, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
[10/Nov/2016 15:56:04] "POST /projects/5915/submit_3_5_ajax/ HTTP/1.1" 500 21537` which I guess might be what you're talking about? I can't find the line `return int(value)` in any of the code I've been looking at (urls.py, views.py, & forms.py), and also couldn't spot it in any of the `ajax.js` files I've just found...